# Mvc3 default authorize filter attribute in IE7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

i have an action method that is called by an ajax call.

The thing is that the authorize action filter is redirecting me right in the case of firefox, but not in IE7. The thing is when i remove the authorize the request is reaching the action method.

What i did is to use the Output cache attribute with the following options: (saw in other stackoverflow question)

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]

[Authorize]
```

But still i have the same issue on IE7 (the redirection doesnt work)

I dont know if maybe is an issue on web.config authentication element:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Pages/LoginRegistration" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE caches AJAX GET requests by default. If your initial reply doesn't specify a `Cache-Control` header (different than what `OutputCache` does -- `Cache-Control` controls the *browser's* cache, not the server's), then IE won't ever request it again, so your authorization does nothing, since the browser never actually talks to the server.

So either include the `Cache-Control` HTTP header in your response or use a `POST`.

Comment: Or attach a random query variable to URL which IE will understand as a new request hence skipping cache checking. jQuery supports this.

Comment: @Robert, that works, but it's kind of brute force, and it arguably delegates to the browser functionality which should live in the server.

Comment: @Crag Stuntz: You're right about the fact that this should be controlled by server. but it's arguable whether this has been delegated to the client since scripts are also sent from the server. And browser checking `cache-control` header could also be understood as client delegation of otherwise server logic. I suppose it's easier to use built-in jQuery (or any other lib) functionality than writing your own code to attach HTTP headers to your responses. It's just a suggestion. Your solution is of course valid and I would accept it as such.

Comment: First thanks for the responses. What i see is that if i call via ajax to an action with the authorize filter attribute (and the user doesnt have the credentials) its return me (instead the page url Pages/LoginRegistration) the content of the page url (<html>....)

Comment: @Jose3d: `AuthorizeAttribute` returns HTTP 401 Unauthorized when the user is not authenticated. Forms auth intercepts HTTP 401 Unauthorized at the server and replaces them with HTTP 200 and the login page. That's what you're seeing. We work around this by subtyping `AuthorizeAttribute` and returning HTTP 403 Forbidden instead for AJAX requests.